# Scatter chart using highstocks?

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

[image]

I need to create a chart like above using highstocks. I tried candlestick but it is not working, i.e. it is not showing any data. What am I doing wrong ? Can anybody guide me through it ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle example

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I used another type of highstock chart rather than candlestick which worked like a charm.

Comment: So at this momemnt, all works properly ?

Comment: yes, most of the work as intended. The only problem at the moment is the start date of the graph, where the graph is shown by default of the last month, not from today. I have no idea how to fix that.